# how do i implement following slider sleekbar in flutter with exactly same design

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[image]

I want to implement exactly the same slider widget in the app, I found many packages, but I want the same design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try CircularProgressIndicator:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
              strokeWidth: 10,
            ),
```

and then use Column and Stack,

```
Column
  Stack
    CircularProgressIndicator(),
    Text('50%'),
  Text('Nutrition'),
```

Comment: but will the color and text change according to the input, for example if the progress is only 20%, and the color should cover only 20% of the circle.

Comment: yep, there is a parameter 'value', you can assign any value like 20~